# Modify SqlDataSource.SelectCommand using Stored Procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatasource

I am trying to create a search box in my application, in order to do so i need to modify the SqlDataSource.SelectCommand. I will appreciate any help!

For testing I did it like this, it works but it is vulnerable for sql injection

```
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "sp_offer_search '" + txtSearch.Text + "', " +   Session["customerId"] + " , '" + "Pending"+ "'";
   GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is What I tried so far but it is not working:

```
 if (txtSearch.Text != "")
        {                
         //open connection
          oCn.Open();
          SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, oCn);
          com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable", txtSearch.Text);  
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId",Session["customerId"]);   
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text);   


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = dt.ToString();
            GridView1.DataBind();
       }
```

Comment: Exactly how does it now work?  Do you get an error, or incorrect returns, or nothing returned?  Something else?

Comment: it doesn't return anything, it like it doesn't find a match

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Marc_s thank you for the hands up. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! Here is what I tried and it works. I hope this can b helpful for someone.

```
  if (txtSearch.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                //  open connection
                oCn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_offer_search", oCn);

                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Variable", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearch.Text;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["customerId"];
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Pending";

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oCn.Close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the GridView datasource is set to the SqlDataSource1 then you don't need the DataTable. And a DataTable.ToString() is not a selectCommand. Try:

```
 if (txtSearch.Text != "")
    {                        
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, oCn);
      com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable", txtSearch.Text);  
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId",Session["customerId"]);   
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text);   

      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = com;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```

Comment: Hi Crowcoder, "com" is returning System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand and is causing an error:'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' is not supported in this version of SQL Server any ideas?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: we are using SQL Azure

Comment: I've only used EntityFramework against SQL Azure. I found this (https://www.axian.com/2014/12/01/adjustments-for-sql-azure-no-ole-db/) that implies the ADO.Net OleDB provider might work. But if you are going to switch the provider I would suggest EntityFramework.